# I want to create a java object from the resultset of a select query

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Connection to JDBC is working fine. But I don't get any output.
This is the code which accesses database tables.
File name - FlightDB.java

```
public static Flight selectFlight(Flight flight) throws SQLException{
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String q1 = "Select * from Flights1 f order by f.time";
        Flight flight1 = null;
        try{
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(q1);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                flight = Display.showFlights(rs);
            //  flight1 = new Flight();
//              flight1.setflno(rs.getInt(1));
//              flight1.settime(rs.getTimestamp(2));
            }
        }
        finally{
            closeResultSet(rs);
            closePreparedStatement(ps);
        }
        return flight;

    }
```

And this is a part of top-level code------------
        File name : Display.java

```
static Flight showFlights(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        Flight flight1 = new Flight();
//      Flight flight = new Flight(flno,time);
//      FlightDB.selectFlight(flight);
        flight1.setflno(rs.getInt(1));
        flight1.settime(rs.getTimestamp(2));
        System.out.println("New flight " + flight1.getflno());
        return flight1;
}
```

And this is my class Flight ---- Flight.java

```
public Flight() {
            flno = 0;
             time = null;
        }
        public Flight(int flno  ,Timestamp time)
        {
            this.flno = flno;
            this.time = time;

        }
        public int getflno(){
            return flno;
        }
        public void setflno(int flno){
            this.flno = flno;
        }
        public Timestamp gettime(){
            return time;
        }
        public void settime(Timestamp time){
             this.time = time;
        }
```

Thank you for looking at this code. I am not sure where I am going wrong. Can you please help me in this. Thanks.

Comment: The line `System.out.println("New flight " + flight1.getflno());` attempts to concatentate the `int` from `Flight.getflno` with the static string literal `"New flight "`. Just one of many issues in your roll-your-own ORM attempt here.

Answer (score 0):

is your table name is `Flights1`
Do you see any exceptions in logs?
Can you try this

```
 ps = connection.prepareStatement(q1);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
 Flight flight1 = new Flight();
 flight1.setflno(rs.getInt(1));
 flight1.settime(rs.getTimestamp(2));
 System.out.println("New flight " + flight1.getflno());}
```

Comment: Yes the table schema is Flights1(flno int, time Timestamp)

Comment: Yes, it worked. I added the code. And changed the Display.java code to       static Flight showFlights(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException                    {
        Flight flight1 = new Flight();
        FlightsDB.selectFlight(flight1);
        return flight1;
        }
}